# Unable to set value using net-snmp c API

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to set a value for an OID using `net-snmp` `C` api, snippet of the code that I am using is:

```
char *ltmp = "description";

char *buff = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
strcpy(buff,ltmp);

if (!snmp_parse_oid(".1.3.6.1.4.1.2162.1.2.2.1.0", anOID, &anOID_len)) {
    snmp_perror(".1.3.6.1.4.1.2162.1.2.2.1.0");
    SOCK_CLEANUP;
    exit(1);
} else if (snmp_pdu_add_variable(pdu, anOID, anOID_len,'s',buff, (int)strlen(buff))) {
    snmp_perror(".1.3.6.1.4.1.2162.1.2.2.1.0");
}
```

when I run this code, it throws the following error

> Internal error in type switching
>
> Error in packet
>
> Reason: (badValue) The value given has the wrong type or length.

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using one of the predefined constants for the variable type; in this case `ASN_OCTET_STR` instead of `s`.

From [`asn1.h`](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/dev/agent/asn1_8h_source.html):

```
#define ASN_BOOLEAN         ((u_char)0x01)
#define ASN_INTEGER         ((u_char)0x02)
#define ASN_BIT_STR         ((u_char)0x03)
#define ASN_OCTET_STR       ((u_char)0x04)
#define ASN_NULL            ((u_char)0x05)
#define ASN_OBJECT_ID       ((u_char)0x06)
#define ASN_SEQUENCE        ((u_char)0x10)
#define ASN_SET             ((u_char)0x11)
```

Comment: thanks, could you please tell me if mib supports double or float data types and if they do. which among the above cases you mentioned should be used to access them?

Comment: No, there are no floats. You can send as a string.